# Métodos de armazenamento de imagens

Tags: mysql, imagem, blob, base64

Estou estudando qual a melhor maneira de armazenar algumas imagens dos usuários que são cadastrados em meu sistema.

Encontrei 3 maneiras de se resolver esse problema: **Salvar em um diretório local**, **Salvar como BLOB** e **Salvar como Base64**.

Gostaria de saber quais os prós e contras dessas opções e qual delas se destacaria das demais. E também se existe alguma outra maneira de salvar essas imagens.

Comment: De cara, posso dizer que Base64 ocupa 25% a mais de espaço do que as outras 2 opções e para armazenamento não faz sentido. Para transmissão, aí talvez seja ser necessário dependendo muito do meio utilizado. (os detalhes deixo para quem for postar resposta completa).

Comment: Aliás, o correto é eu dizer que Base64 ocupa 33% a mais do que a informação original. 25% é apenas o _overhead_ contido na informação codificada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Vantagens de Salvar em um diretório local:** Não usa espaço do seu banco
>   de dados, e sim da própria área de aramazenamento do sistema, isso faz
>   o armazenamento ser mais barato e
>       ser mais simples caso você precise salvar apenas a imagem, só criar uma estrutura de armazenamento conforme suas necessidades.
>
> **Vantagens de armazenamento em Blob:** Se você possuir espaço de sobra
>   para banco de dados, esse é um ótimo método visto que você pode
>   adicionar colunas complementares a imagem salva
>       contendo mais informaçoes sobre elas, chega a ser mais facil de programar porque linguagens de programaçao novas trazem ferramentas que
>   facilitam o armazenamento e também é mais facil de organizar pois elas
>   ficam entabeladas em um DB.
>
> **Sobre armazenamento em BASE64:** Não recomendado pelo aumento do tamanho
>   da imagem em até 25%, esse método seria como uma alternativa de
>   transmissão da imagem.

Comment: Sobre armazenamento em diretório local, isso é 100% verdade, depois de um tempo, tudo acaba ficando confuso demais. Renomear a imagem como id e tudo mais acaba sendo um gerenciamento complicado caso você tenha coleções, "imagens dentro de imagens" ex: sistema imobiliário, se tem a foto de capa e as fotos do imóvel, diferenciar acaba sendo mais complicado e bagunçado.

Comment: Entendi, mais uma dúvida. Se eu tenho várias imagens salvas em um diretório é mais viável eu passar essas imagens pro Front end utilizando Base64 ou então eu carregar essas imagens no Front direto do diretório?

Comment: A codificação Base64 é frequentemente utilizada quando existe uma necessidade de transferência e armazenamento de dados binários para um dispositivo designado para trabalhar com dados textuais. Esta codificação é amplamente utilizada por aplicações em conjunto com a linguagem de marcação XML, possibilitando o armazenamento de dados binários em forma de texto. Acho que não tem essa necessidade extrema de utilizar Base64 para você retornar sua imagem. Você precisa esconder o diretório onde está a imagem?

Comment: Já que o sistema ira ficar na rede local creio que não tenho a necessidade de esconder o diretório

Answer (score 1):

Minha resposta é baseada nas seguintes respostas de dezenas encontradas no SOEN
[1](https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=pt-BR&prev=search&rurl=translate.google.com.br&sl=en&u=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay&usg=ALkJrhizfDl6JsAr4o-tMeOAUP-32HCHUg)
[2](https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=pt-BR&prev=search&rurl=translate.google.com.br&sl=en&u=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722603/storing-image-in-database-directly-or-as-base64-data&usg=ALkJrhge7eUx1MhfwReYIIZZraTLLTrMuA)
[3](https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=pt-BR&prev=search&rurl=translate.google.com.br&sl=en&u=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561447/store-pictures-as-files-or-in-the-database-for-a-web-app&usg=ALkJrhi8lIu9SKxHYZLywwaubmrodWaAfA)

**Diretório Local**

1. As imagens podem ser facilmente armazenados em cache quando
   armazenados no sistema de arquivos.
2. Manter imagens em DB é mais caro que manter em um sistema de arquivos.
3. Em termos de performance é provavelmente melhor armazenar o arquivo
   no sistema de arquivos e apenas escrever o nome do arquivo ou
   caminho do arquivo e, talvez, o tipo de mime para o banco de dados.
4. Outra razão para ir para o sistema de arquivos é quando você tem que
   compartilhar seus dados (imagens ou sons, vídeo, qualquer que seja)
   com acesso de terceiros: no caso aplicação web que usa imagens que
   têm de ser acessado a partir de "fora" da rede local de tal forma que
   um acesso de banco de dados para recuperar dados binário é
   simplesmente impossível.
5. Você não terá problemas com o aumento da carga DB e conexões que
   consomem (que pode ser caro para servidores de banco de dados por
   conexãolicenciados).

**Banco de Dados**

1. A razão para armazenar binários (imagens) em um banco de dados é a
   contenção. Quando todos os dados estiverem em um banco de dados,
   dessa forma simplifica muito a estratégia de backup.